# Read access violation exception for a delete function c++

Tags: c++, exception, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person{
public:
    string name;
    int age, height, weight;

    Person(string name = "empty", int age = 0, int height = 0, int weight = 0) {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
        this->height = height;
        this->weight = weight;
    }
    Person operator = (const Person &P) {
        name = P.name;
        age = P.age;
        height = P.height;
        weight = P.weight;

        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Person& p) {
    os << "Name: " << p.name << "   " << "Age: " << p.age << "     " << "Height: " << p.height << " " << "Weight: " << p.weight << "\n";
    return os;
};

class Node {
public:
    Person* data;
    Node* next;
    Node(Person*A) {
        data = A;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node * head;
    LinkedList() {
        head = nullptr;
    }

    void InsertAtHead(Person*A) {
        Node* node = new Node(A);
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }
    void InsertAtEnd(Person*A) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            InsertAtHead(A);
        }
        else {
            Node* node = new Node(A);
            Node* temp = head;
            while (temp->next != nullptr) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = node;
        }
    }
    void InsertAtPosition(Person*A, int pos) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            InsertAtHead(A);
        }
        else {
            Node* node = new Node(A);
            Node* temp = head;
            for (int i = 1; i < pos - 1; i++) { temp = temp->next; }
            node->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = node;
        }
    }
    void DeleteByValue(string search_name) {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            if (temp->data->name == search_name) {
                delete(temp);
            }
            else {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        cout << "No person with that name was in the list" << endl;
    }

    void DeleteFromHead() {
        if (head != nullptr) {
            Node* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    void DeleteFromEnd() {
        Node* prev = nullptr;
        Node* temp = head;
        if (head == nullptr) { cout << "Nothing to delete" << endl; }
        else if (head->next == nullptr) { DeleteFromHead(); }
       else {
            while (temp->next != nullptr) {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            prev->next = nullptr;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    void DeleteAtPosition(int pos) {
        Node* prev = nullptr;
        Node* temp = head;
        if (head == nullptr) { cout << "Nothing to delete" << endl; }
        else if (pos == 1) { DeleteFromHead(); }
        else {
            for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            prev->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    void UpdateAtPosition(Person*A, int pos) {
        if (head == nullptr) { cout << "No element in the list"; return; }
        if (pos == 1) { head->data = A; }
        else {
            Node* temp = head;
            for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->data = A;
        }
    }

    void Print() {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            cout << *(temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    LinkedList* list = new LinkedList();
    Stack* stack = new Stack(3);
    DynamicStack* dstack = new DynamicStack();


    cout << "Linked List" << endl;
    cout << "-----------" << endl;
    list->InsertAtHead(new Person("Jeremy", 22, 70, 145));                  list->Print();
    list->InsertAtHead(new Person("Samantha", 20, 63, 115));                list->Print();
    list->InsertAtEnd(new Person("Chris", 19, 70, 200));                    list->Print();
    list->DeleteByValue("Chris");                                           list->Print();
    list->InsertAtPosition(new Person("Grace", 15, 64, 150), 3);            list->Print();
    list->InsertAtPosition(new Person("Robert", 15, 67, 160), 4);           list->Print();
    list->DeleteFromHead();                                                 list->Print();
    list->DeleteFromEnd();                                                  list->Print();
    list->DeleteAtPosition(2);                                              list->Print();
    list->UpdateAtPosition(new Person("Jeremy", 23, 70, 155), 1);           list->Print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I am new to C++ and I am trying to create a function for my linked list class that will Delete a Person object by the Persons name. I know this isn't showing the rest of the class, but I know it is all working and the error lies within this function. When I try and run the program there is an exception being thrown saying "Read Access Violation" on the line "delete(temp);". I am confident that I need to move the rest of the nodes back and make another node such as "prev" to store temp in before deleting it, but I have tried a lot and as I said I am new. Can anyone tell me what I need to add to get this to work, and please explain why so I am learning from it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *but I know it is all working and the error lies within this function.* -- No, C++ does not work this way.  You could have corrupted memory long before this function is called.  Memory corruption can be silent, and you won't know anything is wrong until too late.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have tested it in a debugger and previous to adding this function and it all works until that one line was added.

Comment: You forgot to reset the pointers after `delete`. They continue to refer to released memory.

Comment: You claim all the other code is working.   I don't believe it.   The most common cause of a `delete` expression failing is SOME OTHER CODE doing something untoward with a pointer.   The only possibility of failure in the code you have shown occurs if `temp->data` is a null or invalid pointer (in which case, accessing `temp->data->name` and comparing it with `search_name` would have undefined behaviour) or that your code accesses `temp` after deleting it (also undefined behaviour).  If that is not the case, then the problem is in code you haven't shown - whether you believe it is working or not

Comment: Were you supposed to use `delete` on that line?  If so, then that is **not** the mistake.  All `delete` is telling you is that you're calling `delete`on a bogus pointer.  How that pointer became bogus -- that is in the code you are not showing us (the code you are claiming "works").

Comment: @AndersK. - the operand of `delete` is an expression.  `(temp)` is a valid expression.

Comment: @Peter okay I posted all the code

Comment: @Fall0ut What about  a `main` function that shows the usage of the classes that reproduces the error?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie okay there is main as well. Sorry sometimes people try and tell me to keep things short and concise so I tried this time. Hope that helps.

Comment: Several of your functions have loops that keep doing `temp = temp->next` a specified number of times or until a conditions is met, with no check that `temp` or `temp->next` are NULL.

Comment: @Fall0ut You could have shortened `main` by removing the `DynamicStack` stuff.  It is not necessary.  Also, in C++ there is no need to create objects using `new`, as you're doing here: `LinkedList* list = new LinkedList();`.  C++ is not Java -- all you had to do is `LinkedList list;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie At my previous college we coded in Java so that is definitely a useful tip, thank you!

Comment: @Fall0ut -- Also, you're leaking memory.  Your `LinkedList` class lacks a destructor to remove the nodes when the `LinkedList` is destroyed.  As to Java, C++ is not forgiving as Java when it comes to error detection.  You make a mistake in Java, you get an exception with a nice stack trace.  You make a mistake in C++, and you won't know it until you demo your application in front of new clients.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have not learned about destructors yet, I will look into it and add one for practice though. I really appreciate all of this.

Comment: Try replacing all owning pointers by `std::unique_ptr`, most likely this will also solve your bug

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you. I did some further research on this, and read that I can use "typedefs" is this better practice, or is it best to just write std::cout each and every time?

Comment: Personally, I tend to write `std::cout`, `std::endl`, `std;:system` and the rest in full when I need them, but other alternatives include `using std::cout;` inside your `main()` or (for objects, such as `std::cout`) declaring an alias variable (e.g. `auto& cout = std::cout;`).  But keep the scope small, and the names to import specific (rather than the entire namespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your

```
void DeleteByValue(string search_name) {
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        if (temp->data->name == search_name) {
            delete(temp);
        }
        else {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    cout << "No person with that name was in the list" << endl;
}
```

once you find a match you just delete the memory but there is more to it, you need to handle both the previous node as well as head node if the name is found in the first node.

something like this

```
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        if (temp->data->name == search_name) {
            if (prev != nullptr) {
              prev->next = temp->next;
            }
            else {
               head = temp->next;
            }
            delete temp;
            temp = nullptr;  
        }
        else {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this finally worked. Im going to have to step through this slowly because I was clearly missing a lot. This seems to go along with @FeiXiang explanation below. I appreciate it a ton.

Answer (score 2):

After you find a match, you delete it and the loop keeps going since you never set `temp` to `nullptr`. `temp` now is no longer valid since it has just been deleted, however, you try to access the data it points to on the next iteration, producing undefined behavior, then you delete it, likely causing the crash.

To fix it, either break the loop after a match is found or keep track of the next node before you delete temp.

Also, you should not have an output statement in the delete function since another person or you in the future won't expect a function that deletes elements to print stuff to the screen.